# <HTTP> <BEA-101163> <Could not load user defined listener:

Tags: java, weblogic

I have modified an EAR for Weblogic 10 ( BEA 10 )which is already running on BEA  8..

I am getting the following error while deploying the EAR..

*[HTTP:101163]Could not load user defined listener: com.xxx.xxxx.jmx.LifecycleListener java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tibco/sdk/MException at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2357) at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2671) at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:321) at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:303) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.getNewInstance(WebComponentContributor.java:187) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.createListenerInstance*

Have you faced this error ?Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

From the Exception it seems that some library is missing from your ear file. Make sure that com.xxx.xxxx.jmx.LifecycleListener is a valid package and included correctly in your ear.

If you are developing and building the ear with JDeveloper make sure you add this lib in your application resources. If you do this manualy make sure that this lib exists in your WEB-INF/lib folder